# Simplify log of log

Tags: logarithms

Is it possible to simplify $\log_2(\log_2(x))$ to a single log of some base, and possibly some power or multiplier for x? Or some other way?
Or anything that doesn't involve a double log?

Comment: If so: no. Changing the base of the logarithm will make a difference by a constant factor; while $\log_2\log_2 x$ is *exponentially smaller* than $\log_2 x$.

Comment: Thanks. But is there another way - like I also ask for? E.g raising the log2 to some power?

Comment: Note sure exactly what you are asking for, but can you use $$2^{\log_2(x)} = x?$$

Comment: Nope, this is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: Try any way that doesn't involve double logs

Comment: If you have a term of the form $log(x)log(log(x))$ then it can be "simplified" in terms of the Lambert W function. You can also simplify $log(log(x)$. For example $log(x)log(log(x)) = y$ is equivalent to $log(log(x)) = W(y)$ and to $log(x) = y/W(y)$

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Suppose that $y=\log_2(\log_2x)$.

Then $2^y=\log_2x$ and $2^{(2^y)}=x$.

Essentially what OP is asking is whether there exists a base $b$ such that $b^y=x$. Let us suppose there were.

Let $b^y=x=2^{(2^y)}$. Then $y=\log_b2^{(2^y)}=2^y\log_b2$.

Therefore, $\log_b2=y\cdot 2^{-y}$

But $\log_b2$ is a constant and $y\cdot 2^{-y}$ is not a constant.

So there can be no base $b$ such that $b^y=2^{(2^y)}$ and therefore no way to simplify $\log_2(\log_2y)$ to some $\log_by$.